# StackExchange.Redis How to Connect to Sentinel

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I want to get notificated when a master changes

For this i wanted to connect to my sentinels but the connection Multiplexer tells me that the are not reachable.

What am I Doing wrong?

```
 ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:26380,localhost:26381,localhost:26382");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there's some tests (https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis.Tests/Sentinel.cs), I'm not sure if there's sentinel feature implemented. You can check in here:

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/22

Comment: This feature is implemented now.

Answer (score 7):

You can try the (much) newer version of StackExchange.Redis which comes with [sentinel mode](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration) feature. You can now connect in sentinel mode with connection string like this:

```
var conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("172.17.6.45:26379,serviceName=mymaster");
```

It will auto-discover current master and return a managed connection which will handle the failover for you. If you want to be notified for master change you can subscribe the `ConnectionMultiplexer.ConfigurationChanged` event.

Comment: So, original (master) host/port should just be replaced with sentinel host/port and that's it?

Comment: Besides sentinel host/port, you also need to specify the serviceName parameter to trigger the sentinel mode. You can also have a list of sentinels in your connection string or your Redis Configuration object so that even when some of the sentinels are down, as long as your application can reach one of them everything will still work.